# Meteor update with $push to an array that doesn't already exist on a single record

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have been through as many of the answers here on StackOverflow but am still having an issue.

First I don't get any errors in the console on the client or in the terminal console. The return says success yet it does not update.

I'm using a method on the SERVER as follows:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

Meteor.methods({
   'agentPageAccess'({userID, pageID}) {
      Pages.update({ "PageID" : pageID }, {
        $push: { "agentAccess" : { "agentID" : userID } }
      });   
    }
});
```

Here is the data before the update is called. Note: the array does not exist and I want it to be added and the data updated in that new array, only if the array does not already exist. If the array does already exist I want it to push the new value to the end of the existing array.

```
{ "_id" : "pPvQezHxC4J4tkGQg", "PageID" : "1234567", "PageName" : "Test Page", "PageToken" : "7654321" }
```

I have checked to make sure the userID and pageID have a value when the method is fired.

Here is the method call on the CLIENT Side:

```
Template.assignAgents.events({
        'submit form': function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let target = event.target;
            let userID = target.userSelect.value;
            let pageID = target.Page.value;

            Meteor.call('agentPageAccess', {
                userID: userID,
                pageID: pageID
            }, (err,res) => {
                if(err){
                    alert(err);
                }else{
                    alert("Agent assigned to page");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I'm a old programmer with many years of experience but new to Meteor. So please talk like I'm new to this platform. Thanks so much for all your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of $pull use $addToSet.
$addToSet will create the array field with the specified value.
Here a link to the mongodb doc [addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/)

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

Meteor.methods({
   'agentPageAccess'({userID, pageID}) {
      Pages.update({ "PageID" : pageID }, {
        $addToSet: { "agentAccess" : { "agentID" : userID } }
      });   
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Michel that was the ticket!!